# How to "queue" the same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm building a elevator simulator using sliders. I  need the "elevators" to move at the same time, so I thought of using threads, but my knowledge is basic on this topic. ;) I got the elevators to move via threads (see code below) but I'm stuck on the option to move a specific elevator to one floor (e.g. from floor 4 to floor 10) **AND THEREAFTER TO ANOTHER FLOOR** (e.g. floor 1) If I just create the threads, the elevator tries to move in both directions simultaneously! So I tried to check if the thread name existed already, and then it will only move in one direction. Problem is that it then ignores the second command to move in the other direction. I assume that it has to do with the fact that the thread name still exists, or maybe that the code execution has moved past the second 'command' to move to floor 1? Please help!

```
private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
  moveLift(1, 10); //moves lift 1 to floor 10
  moveLift(1, 1); //should move lift 1 to floor 1 from 10
  moveLift(2, 10); //moves lift 2 to floor 10
}

private void moveLift(int liftNum, int floorNum) {
  boolean b = false;
  Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
  for (Thread t : threads) {
    String name = t.getName();
    if (name.equals("Lift" + liftNum)) {
      b = true;
    }
  }
  if (!b) {
    MyThread mt = new MyThread(liftNum, floorNum);
    mt.setName("Lift" + liftNum);
    mt.start();
  }
}
```

Any advise on queuing the moveLift commands so the threads don't fight each other?

Comment: "I'm building a elevator simulator using sliders": I haven't read the rest of your comment, but, I wonder whether simulating it using something like consecutive discrete steps of time slots might be more appropriate. Each step would compute an approximation of what happens in a specific time slot, and each time slot would be the same length. This approach is used in various kinds of simulations as well as real-time game engines. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_simulation .

Comment: As a new contributor, my initial question might not have been clear enough. Yes, there are multiple ways to write any piece of code, but I really like to try to get an answer for this specific code. All I'm really asking is how to queue the moveLift(1, 1) after moveLift(1, 10). Since they both reference the same lift (1), is there a way I can adapt the code in moveLift method? I've already got it to ignore the second call to the same lift with the boolean b, but the program does not just ignore it but actually does not do it.

Comment: Part of a bigger program so I'd like to write code that is independent from other code.

Comment: Well, in case you are new to programming, I would encourage you to be careful with using threads. Using them correctly can be (very or extremely) difficult, especially if you have shared mutable state across threads, and all kinds of weird behaviours might arise if it is not done correctly. You can read more here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html , though that is a somewhat superficial treatment and written for Java 8.

Comment: That said, I like your idea and concept of having a somewhat "declarative" way of describing what you want with `moveLift(1, 10);` and the other commands.

Comment: I can see that you are using `java.awt.event`, which indicates that you might be using Swing. There's also JavaFX, which is newer, though JavaFX has become a somewhat independent project since its initial development.

Comment: If I was you, and I think I could do it, I would probably continue with your idea of having something like `moveLift`, except instead of `moveLift` being a method that attempts to execute it, I would instead let `moveLift` return a data type that describes what I want to happen (ie. move lift number `x` to floor `y`), maybe called `MoveLiftCommand`. I would then have a queue data structure, maybe some class that implements the `Queue` interface https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html (I have included the API reference for Java 14 here) (continued).

Comment: (continued) , maybe `LinkedList`, and then add the commands to that queue - your commands as data. I would then have a separate method that handles the commands describe in the queue. The advantage of using a queue is that you can then poll the queue, take the top-most element (if any) and handle that, and once that has been handled, you can handle the next, and repeat until the queue is empty. How to design the system reg. that depends on what you want to do and how you want to approach it, but it does sound a little bit involved. But again, I would avoid threads if I was you.